# How to keep album art same in Windows Media Player

Tags: mp3, windows-media-player, music, album-art

I have a few albums that I made myself, (because I downloaded songs from the internet and they're not from albums and I hate the unknown album thing so i make my own) and I try to add album art. (by copying and pasting album art) I do it to one of the albums and sets the picture I tried to paste as the album art for all of the albums that I made. How do I make it paste to just one album?

Comment: Are the music files for each album located in a separate folder on the file system?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a better tool for this job. Something like [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) for example.

> Mp3tag is a powerful and yet easy-to-use tool to edit metadata of
>   common audio formats where it supports ID3v1, ID3v2.3, ID3v2.4, iTunes
>   MP4, WMA, Vorbis Comments and APE Tags.
>
> It can rename files based on the tag information, replace characters
>   or words in tags and filenames, import/export tag information, create
>   playlists and more.
>
> Mp3tag supports online database lookups from, e.g., Amazon, discogs,
>   or freedb, allowing you to automatically gather proper tags and cover
>   art for your music library.
>
> Mp3tag supports the following audio formats:
>
> ```
> Advanced Audio Coding (aac)
> Direct Stream Digital Audio (dsf)
> Free Lossless Audio Codec (flac)
> Monkey's Audio (ape)
> Mpeg Layer 3 (mp3)
> MPEG-4 (mp4 / m4a / m4b / m4v / iTunes)
> Musepack (mpc)
> Ogg Vorbis (ogg)
> IETF Opus (opus)
> OptimFROG (ofr / ofs)
> Speex (spx)
> Tom's Audio Kompressor (tak)
> True Audio (tta)
> Windows Media Audio (wma)
> WavPack (wv)
> ```

[image: 1]

Modify the tags and album art for only the files you want, then right-click them in Windows Explorer and click the *read-only* checkbox to prevent any mistaken changes.

Answer (score 0):

Save your album arts into a folder. 
Click the pciture you want to use as an album art and right click then copy. 
Go to Windows Media Player
Choose an Album Right click and choose "paste album art"

Unfortunately, you have to this one by one in each of your album. You can't paste same album art to all of the albums at the same time.